# How to remove a wallpaper on 22.04 LTS after applying it?

Tags: desktop-background, removing

I wanted to choose a wallpaper by right clicking and selecting "Configure Desktop and Wallpapers".

I tested this using a a .jpg image and clicked "+Add Image" and then OK.
I didn't like the image, so I started looking for a way to remove the the image but I couldn't find a way. How do I remove a wallpaper image after applying it?

Answer (score 1):

A wallpaper is mandatory so there is no removing the current wallpaper;

What you do is set another wallpaper replacing the current so use the same method as you used to add the image you do not longer want and then pick another image or a solid color.

Comment: I have experienced the absense of a wallpaper in Ubuntu before. It's either solid black or solid purple (depending on the version of Ubuntu).

Comment: that is a solid color wallpaper ;-)

Comment: All I'm saying is that once the wallpaper is removed there is a solid color wallpaper. Obviously there would be some kind of color there because you can't just have NOTHING on your screen...

Answer (score 0):

I'm just copy-pasting an answer that works for me from https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/vbipfu/how_to_remove_background_image_2204_lts/

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri ""
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark ""
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color '#3B6EA5'
```